# PhoneGap / jQuery Mobile - Android (2.3 and 2.2) $.mobile defined, but $.mobile.initializePage undefined

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Developing PhoneGap (3.0) Android application and integrating jQueryMobile (1.3.2), with jQuery (1.9.1).

**Edited**: Changed jQ version to 1.9.1 per jQM 1.3 spec.  Was previously using 1.10.  Still having the same issue however.

I am using the following code to make sure that both jQM and deviceready have fired:

```
var app = {
deviceReadyDeferred: $.Deferred(),
jqmReadyDeferred: $.Deferred(),

init: function () {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () { app.deviceReadyDeferred.resolve(); });

    $(document).one("mobileinit", function () {
        app.jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();
    });

    $.when(app.deviceReadyDeferred, app.jqmReadyDeferred).then(app.loaded);
},

loaded: function () {
    /* CODE OMITTED: create new page from ajax data, and insert into DOM */
    $.mobile.initializePage();
    $.mobile.changePage("#pageID");
}
```

Everything works great in Android version higher than 2.3 and iOS.  However, in Android 2.3/2.2 when I get to `$.mobile.initializePage()`, then I am getting `$.mobile.initializePage` as `'undefined'`.  Any ideas why this might be happening in Android 2.3 and below?  I am getting the `mobileinit` event just fine. Both the jQM and jQ versions I am using say that they are compatible with Android 2.3 and 2.2.

Thank you for any help and wisdom towards my issue!

Comment: For JQM 1.3 use jquery 1.9

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, still getting `undefined` for `$.mobile.initializePage`.

Comment: According to docs, initializePage will be triggered automatically. If you remove it, does it change anything?

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I removed initializePage, and now I'm getting the error "cannot call method 'trigger' of undefined" on `$.mobile.changePage`.  I isolated the error in jQM 1.3 to line 4493 when it calls `mpc.trigger( pbcEvent, triggerData );`